# SQLMap remake in JavaScript? Possible?

Tags: javascript, sqlmap

I am trying to expand my JavaScript knowledge about web requests and they way it communicates with external applications. I am wondering if it is possible to make use of the xhr object in order to make a basic sqlmap alternative(*SQLmap is a tool for exploiting SQL vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a tool 'a firefox Addon' [SQL Inject Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/sql-inject-me/), here is the link of it's xpi file ' [sql_inject_me-0.4.7-fx.xpi](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/229626/sql_inject_me-0.4.7-fx.xpi) ' , and since Firefox addons uses JavaScript you can check it out and see how to make your own Js'based attack vector.